# Grails 3 Calling External Methods

Tags: grails

I have a class that holds a users session, such as their username, phone number, and domain. For all intents and purposes, this is how its base looks like:

```
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String domain;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRole(final String role) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }

    public List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

I have a class that extracts this user from the context, and renders its attributes. This is how this class looks like:

```
class UserSession {

    def getLoggedInUser() {
        User user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
        println("################### we are gonna return " + user)
        return user.domain + "\\" + user.username
    }

}
```

The issue I am having is that I do not know how to call getLoggedInUser from the main layout gsp (base template).

I have tried doing something like this so far:

```
<g:set var="userSession" bean="UserSession"/>
<span id="userInfo">${userSession.loggedInUser}</span>
```

However, the page is left blank and the method is never invoked. My question then is: How can I call a method from a base layout gsp, not within every controller, that can be accessed from a specific bean/class?

Comment: Have you tried to make the getLoggedInUser method static?

Btw, not using spring security?
You could just do <sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username" />

Comment: ah, that sec: tag worked like a charm. thanks! I suppose you should write the answer, so I can mark it as answered

Comment: I added it as an aswer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to make the getLoggedInUser method static? probably it would work.

Btw, not using spring security? You could just do `<sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username" />`